# no me permite calcular la cantidad

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El enunciado: Mostrar el id, nombre, ciudad del cliente y cantidad de cuentas que posee en el banco y el monto total del saldo de todas las cuentas.

pdta: la cantidad de cuentas y el monto debo hacerla por funciones en la imagen se aprecia la primera función de prueba pero me sale este error

Codigo :

```
create or replace function  calculoCantidad(nombre_sucursal character varying)
returns integer as
    $body$
    declare
        calcular integer;
    BEGIN
        select distinct
        count(c.id)
        into calcular
        from sucursales su
        inner join cuentas cu on ( su.nombre = cu.nombre_sucursal)
        inner join cuentas_clientes cc on cu.numero = cc.numero_cuenta
        inner join clientes c on cc.id_cliente = c.id
        where
            su.nombre = $1;
        return calcular;
    end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: estas enviando un int en el select y tu funcion recive un charvaring

Comment: prueba este sql `select id, nombre, ciudad, calculoCantidad(id::text)`